# My php Scripts is very slow at server

Tags: php, memcached, cassandra

i'm testing an app hosted at: app.promls.net, but there is some mistake on the script execution, on localhost 
takes only -> timer: 0.12875008583069 seconds. . 
in the execution when is just plain text that are created via php.
and when content is created dinamically and cames from mysql database: 
timer: 0.44203495979309 seconds.  /timer: 0.65762710571289 seconds. / timer: 0.48272085189819 seconds. 
the times are diferent on the server. takes like 8 seconds on execution.

does anyone could give me a recomendation of how test and optimize my php execution. 
i was optimizing the mysql database, cause some querys returns a tons of rows for a simple search, using describe and explain.
but know i have finished, and i would like to explore some new options for php execution.
i know that adding compression to html helps, but it only help on time of trasportation between server and final host when returns an html response. know i want to optimize php execution and if there are some tricks on mysql that could be implemented to help me improve the time response better.

note: i have thinking in use the hiphop for php and memcache or cassandra. but i guess those thinks are not re result for problem, cause i have no activities( means user actions) and no much information on my app.

thanks in advance i'm available for any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

with such a big difference on execution we would need details on the host configuration (shared? dedicated?).

Is mysql skipping DNS test? if not try using **skip-name-resolve** setting in my.cnf, or use IP and not DNS in the PRIVILEGE query/user table, the only time I have seen such latency it was because of DNS timeout in the connection between MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First, off, try doing the following to your MYSQL DB:

1. Run  "OPTIMIZE TABLE mytable" on all of your tables
2. Run "ANALYZE TABLE mytable" on all of your tables.
3. Add indexes to the table fields that you are using

Be sure to substitute each table name for "mytable" in the above statements.

See if doing the first two makes a difference, then add the indexes.